# Visual Basic BadImageFormatException Error Message Connecting to Oracle Database

Tags: database, vb.net, oracle, visual-studio

My visual basic application is trying to connect to an Oracle database but exception error message keeps displaying,

> Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw
>   BadImageFormatExceptions. This problem will occur when running in 64
>   bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client component installed

screenshot

[image: X]

I installed Visual Studio Express Edition 64 bit and Oracle Express Edition 64 bit. Now I'm wondering why I'm getting this kind of error.

Comment: The .NET assembly that is containing the classes your program is using to talk to Oracle (through the drivers) is most likely 32-bit, and you have a 64-bit process, or vice versa (32-bit process, 64-bit assemblies). Have you checked if your program is compiled as 32-bit or 64-bit? What is the target? x64, x86, Any CPU? If the latter, there is a checkbox in the project settings for "prefer 32-bit", can you verify what this is configured to be?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why this error occurs. To work with Oracle database, use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess NuGet package and I also recommend you to tick "Prefer 32-bit" option in project properties. Using Windows integrated Oracle data provider (as in screenshot) is strongly not recommended - it is old and deprecated.